# ArrayList objects (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I stuck with the logic and need help for my project.
I have a text file with 5 vehicle names in it.
Then I have to read them into an `ArrayList`, which I did using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader bTextFileVehicleNames = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("vehicles.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> vechicleNamesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((textFileLine = bTextFileVehicleNames.readLine()) != null)
    { 
        vehicleNamesArray.add(textFileLine);
    }
```

Now, I need to create an object for every item (vehicle name) in the `ArrayList`, which I did using:

```
for(String s : vehicleNamesArray)
{
    newVehicle = new Vehicle(s);
    //I defined this Vehicle newVehicle = null; in the main class. My main is also in the same Vehicle.java file.
}
```

Each of these objects have attributes: `power`, `angle`, `speed`;
and behaviours: `powerOn()`, `powerOff()`, `SpeedUp()`, `SlowDown()`, etc.. which I defined in `Vehicle` class.

Now, the user has to enter Vehicle name command. Then I split them and took `[0]`, which is the vehicle name, and have to first check if it is one of those vehicle names in the `ArrayList` (derived from txt file), and if it is then have to refer it to that particular object I created above. And then have to take in the `[1]`, which is command that corresponds to the particular behaviour of object, which can be `powerOn`, `speedUp`, etc etc..

```
for (int i=0; i< vehicleNamesArray.size(); i++)
{
    if (vehicleNamesArray.get(i).matches(userVehicleName))
      //userVehicleName is the [0] vehicle name entered by user
      //userVehicleCommand is the [1] command entered by user
    {
        switch (userVehicleCommand.toLowerCase()) 
        {
        case "power on":
            newVehicle.powerOn(); //calling that particular bahaviour of the object defined in Vehicle class.
            System.out.println(newVehicle.getName()+" is powered ON.");
            break;
        ...
    ...
```

For example, let's consider there are 5 vehicles in the txt (thereby in the `ArrayList`) named: Audi, Bmw, Mercedez, Volkswagen, Porsche.
The problem is that whatever I enter in the vehicle name command, the program by default is taking the last element, in this case Porsche in the `ArrayList`.
I.e., when I say "Audi, powerON", it still prints out "Porsche is powered ON."

I think I messed up in linking the user entered name to check with the `ArrayList` and then refering it to that particular object.

Comment: Yes, you have **one** `newVehicle` object and you assign each item to it. At the end, the last assignment is what's left. Also, you should use a `try-with-resources` block to close your `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Does your user uses regex? if no in first 'if' statement use .equals(),
and in my expirience switch function works kinda bad with strings, consider using if statements there too

Comment: Your `newVehicle` variable is *one* variable holding *one* vehicle instance, thus if you assign it a value in a loop, it will retain the last one. If you want to have a *list* of vehicles, well, you have to create and populate a list.

Comment: In the `switch` block instead of `newVehicle.getName()` you have to use `vehicleNamesArray.get(i).getName()` or `userVehicleName`

Comment: @Titus where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @BoristheSpider it was a typo, I've copy-pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: @Titus this is still wrong. The OP has a `List<String>` of names. This `List` is looped over and `Vehicle` objects are created - there is no `List<Vehicle>` .

Comment: @RajivGanti your not storing your `Vehicle` objects anywhere you are just setting `newVehicle = new Vehicle("")` the last object in the `arraylist` will be in `newVehicle`...

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are right, I thought he was storing the `Vehicle`s in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep objects created in `List` also :

```
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>;
for(String s : vehicleNamesArray)
{
    newVehicle = new Vehicle(s);
    vehicleList.add(newVehicle);
  //I defined this Vehicle newVehicle = null; in the main class. My main is also in the same Vehicle.java file.
}
```

Then in your second `for loop` retrieve that vehicle object and update it:

```
for (int i=0; i< vehicleNamesArray.size(); i++)
{
    if (vehicleNamesArray.get(i).matches(userVehicleName))
        //userVehicleName is the [0] vehicle name entered by user
        //userVehicleCommand is the [1] command entered by user
    {
        switch (userVehicleCommand.toLowerCase()) 
            {
               case "power on":

               vehicleList.get(i).powerOn(); //calling that particular bahaviour of the object defined in Vehicle class.
               System.out.println(vehicleList.get(i).getName()+" is powered ON.");
               break;
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try storing the vehicles in a `HashMap` or something:

```
HashMap<String, Vehicle> vehicles = new HashMap<String, Vehicles>();

for(String s : vehicleNamesArray)
{
    vehicles.put(s, new Vehicle(s));
}

//Access the vehicle from user input

Vehicle currentVehicle = vehicles.get(userVehicleName);

switch (userVehicleCommand.toLowerCase()) 
{
    case "power on":
    currentVehicle.powerOn(); //calling that particular bahaviour of the object defined in Vehicle class.
    System.out.println(currentVehicle.getName()+" is powered ON.");
    break;
    //etc...
}
```

A `HashMap` can be used to store `key,value` pair in your case `key=carname` `value=Vehicle object`.  This will make it easy to go back and select the car you want based on the user input.  Also currently your not storing your `Vehicle` objects you are only storing the last one...